# Auto.Arima incorrectly predicts first point

Tags: r, time-series, fft, arima

I'm trying to complete a time series analysis of some reservoir data and am using auto.arima with a Fourier component to account for seasonality, as described here https://otexts.com/fpp2/dhr.html#dhr The code I have used is shown below and the dataset I used can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/563nu3daeid0agb/AAB6NSddVUKgBCCbQtuqXPsZa?dl=0

```
Reservoir = read.csv("Reservoir1.csv",TRUE,",")
#impute missing data from data set
Reservoir = imputeTS::na_interpolation(Reservoir)
#Create Time Series
Reservoir = ts(Reservoir[,2],frequency = (365.25),start = c(2013,116))

plots = list()
for (i in seq (10)) {
  fit = auto.arima(Reservoir, xreg = fourier(Reservoir, K = i), seasonal = FALSE)
  plots[[i]] = autoplot(forecast(fit, xreg = fourier(Reservoir, K = i, h=10))) + 
    xlab(paste("K=",i,"AICC=",round(fit[["aicc"]],2))) + ylab("")
}

gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots[[1]],plots[[2]],plots[[3]],plots[[4]],plots[[5]],
                        plots[[6]],plots[[7]],plots[[8]],plots[[9]],plots[[10]],
                        nrow=5)
bestfit = auto.arima(Reservoir, xreg=fourier(Reservoir, K=9), seasonal=FALSE)
summary(bestfit)
checkresiduals(bestfit)
plot(Reservoir,col="red")
lines(fitted(bestfit),col="blue")
```

[image]

The model fits well, except for the incorrect first prediction. I'm lost as to why only this value would be so far off. Or, is this an acceptable error?

Answer (score 2):

The residuals are the one-step forecast errors using all previous observations. At time 1, the residual is the forecast error with no previous observations, so it is simply based on the fitted model. In fact, it is an artificially "good" forecast because the differencing means there is no way for the model to know the location of the data until there is an observation. But the way ARIMA models are implemented in R makes the first prediction use a little more information than it should.

Comment: When you say the forecast is artificially good, are you referring to the entire forecast or simply the forecast at time 1? If the latter, is there a better way to model this system?

Comment: The forecast at time 1. The model is probably ok but that's a different question.